# Origin and Usage of "i wo"?

Tags: etymology, expression, slang

A colloquial way of answering negatively/dismissing an offered statement can be the use of the word(s) "i wo / iwo".

The meaning of "i wo", according to [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/i_wo), is this:

> *(umgangssprachlich)* keineswegs, aber nein, nicht im Geringsten
>
> - drückt aus, dass ein Sprecher die Aussage eines Anderen herunterspielt
> - drückt aus, dass ein Sprecher die Aussage eines Anderen für völlig falsch erklärt

Example:

> "Hast Du ein neues Auto gekauft?" - "**I wo**, das ist ein Mietwagen. Meine alte Kiste ist in der Werkstatt."
>
> "Did you buy a new car?" - "**No way./I'd never do that.** This is a rental car, ... "

Where does that expression come from, and how widespread is its usage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"*Wo"* propably originates from old hig german [(h)wār](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=wo&view=1) and morphed to *"wa, wo, war"* later. This may explain that interjections with a similar meaning like "*Ach was"*, *"Pa wa"*, "*A wa*" share a same etymology. In the [Grimm's](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW24313) we can read:

> IV. wo im gebrauch als interjektion findet sich umgangssprachlich in den verbindungen i wo, ach wo u. ä., die die ablehnung einer für den sprechenden in einer richtung übertrieben oder unsinnig erscheinenden frage ausdrücken; vgl. beispielsweise i wo! etwa = 'wo denkst du hin!' Müller-Fraureuth obersächs.-erzgebirg. 2, 676a; aber wo! 'durchaus nicht!' Jacob Wien 221; a(ch) wo! ja wo! i wo! Fischer schwäb. 6, 911. **diese verwendung von wo wird aus seinem vorkommen in bestimmten redensartlichen wendungen zu erklären sein, die aber nicht mehr faszbar sind;** vgl. die ablehnend formelhaften ellipsen nach i wie i bewahre, i behüte, teil 4, 2, 2014. auf nd. boden **liesze sich i wo auf das redensartliche i wo werd ich denn! Betke Königsb. 66 zurückführen**, wo indessen wo als die nd. form für wie anzusprechen ist.

Accoring to this the interjection *"I wo!"* may originate from idiomatic expression that can not be reconstructed. In the idioma *"I wo werd ich denn!"* it was widely used in prussian regions, then *"wo"* may be related to *"wie*".

Comment: That's all very good so far, however, still the *i* is unexplained. I think it is the more interesting part, since *wo* appears quite often in various usage, but an isolated *i* is actually uniquely used in this expression. Any ideas?